# Python - Pygame random obstacle height issues

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.2, flappy-bird-clone

I currently am working on a 'Flappy Bird' remake in Pygame using Python 3.2. I thought it would be good for practice, and relativly simple. However, it is proving to be hard. Currently, I am having a problem when drawing a rectangle at different heights but keeping the rectangle at the height it is set to.

Here is my *Pipe* class

```
class Pipe:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.drawn = True
        self.randh = random.randint(30,350)
        self.rect = Rect((x,0),(30,self.randh))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-2,0)

    def draw(self,screen):
        self.drawn = True
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,130,30),self.rect)
```

My while Loop is as follows:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        movey = +0.8
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                movey = -2


    x += movex
    y += movey


    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    screen.blit(bird,(x,y))

    Pipe1 = Pipe(scrollx)

    if Pipe1.drawn == True:
        Pipe1.update()
    else:
        Pipe1 = Pipe(scrollx)
        Pipe1.draw(screen)

    scrollx -= 0.3

    pygame.display.update()
```

I have being wrestling with this code for over a week, and I really appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not following the logic of this part:

```
Pipe1 = Pipe(scrollx)

if Pipe1.drawn == True:
    Pipe1.update()
else:
    Pipe1 = Pipe(scrollx)
    Pipe1.draw(screen)
```

The `drawn` attribute is set to `True` at the constructor, so when do you expect the `else` condition to be triggered? Remember you are recreating this pipe *every frame*.

Have you tried drawing the pipe the same you way you did with the bird?

Edit: suggestion for you for loop:

```
PIPE_TIME_INTERVAL = 2

pipes = []    # Keep the pipes in a list.
next_pipe_time = 0

while True:
    [... existing code to handle events and draw the bird ...]

    for pipe in pipes:
        pipe.move(10)     # You'll have to write this `move` function.
        if pipe.x < 0:    # If the pipe has moved out of the screen...
            pipes.pop(0)  # Remove it from the list.

    if current_time >= next_pipe_time:   # Find a way to get the current time/frame.
        pipes.append(Pipe())  # Create new pipe.
        next_pipe_time += PIPE_TIME_INTERVAL  # Schedule next pipe creation.
```

Comment: What I intended to happen is for the drawn variable to be set to False, at which point a pipe would be drawn, then as it is True, it would be moved not drawn

Comment: And the previously created pipe would stop moving? I think you should use a timer for that, not an attribute of Pipe.

Comment: Ive got slightly further now by moving the creation outise of the while loop. Now, all I have to do is work out how to loop when Pipe1's x = 0...

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a suggestion on how to handle more than one pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `Pipe` on every loop, but never hang on to the old one(s), so you get a new random height each time. Move this line:

```
Pipe1 = Pipe(scrollx)
```

outside the `while` loop. Better yet, have a list of pipes you can add new ones to and easily update them all. You never set `self.drawn = False` within `Pipe` either.

Also, you are resetting `movey` for every event, try:

```
movey = 0.8 # no need for plus 
for event in pygame.event.get():
```